# oracle.j2ee.ws.client.jaxws.JRFSOAPFaultException: Client received SOAP Fault from server : Invalid api path

Tags: soap-api-v2

I am trying to invoke **Magento** SOAP V2 **APIs** as web service from Oracle SOA Suite(11.1.1.9) using BPEL. but I am getting  "Invalid API Path"  with error code "3". 
could you please suggest the best approach to get it invoke the required  operations
I am able to invoke default (v1)API with no issues.

Thanks
Kiran